# Identify singularities of: $f(z) = \frac{\sin{(z^2)}}{ze^{\frac{1}{z-3}}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find and identify the kind of singularities (pole, removable, or essential) of the function $f(z) = \frac{\sin{(z^2)}}{ze^{\frac{1}{z-3}}}$.

My approach was to look for discontinuities term by term. We have, $\sin{(z^2)}$ for which sine is a continuous function or $\frac{1}{ze^{\frac{1}{z-3}}} = 0$. Since $z$ is continuous, we have either $\frac{1}{z-3}$  is discontinuous or $\frac{1}{ze^{\frac{1}{z-3}}} = 0$. So the singularities are $z_0 = 3, 0$. Which are removable?

Comment: $lim_{zto0}\frac{zsinz^2}{z^2}$=???

Comment: Isn't $f(3) = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zero of $ze^{\tfrac{1}{z - 3}}$ at $z = 0$ is order $1$, so it cancels with the order $2$ zero of $\sin(z^2)$ at $z = 0$. The singularity at $z = 0$ is thus removable.

The Laurent expansion about $z = 3$ of $e^{-1/(z - 3)}$ is
$$\frac{1}{e^{\tfrac{1}{z - 3}}} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}(z - 3)^{-n},$$
thus the singularity at $z = 3$ is essential.